# Key/Reference of MongoDB table into MYSQL Table

Tags: mysql, mongodb, foreign-keys, grails-orm, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table into MongoDB as "Theme" and a Table in MYSQL as "MSIntegration". I am useing GORM for developing tables and queries.
How Can I use Theme's reference as foreign key in MYSQL ?
Or Without foreign key also is it possible to do ?
Like

```
Class msinstance{
String MSInstance_name
Theme theme
}
```